# How to use SoundCloud API in Java (Android App)

Tags: java, android, api, soundcloud

I am researching for a project and was wondering if I can use SoundCloud API for making and app that streams music with SoundCloud.  I could not find any official source from SoundCloud to privde a Java solution.

Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper

Comment: @Philibobby thanks for your comment. I have seen this page before, but is it the official solution by SoundCloud?

Comment: @Dan as per the readme in that repo, SoundCloud has officially decided to discontinue their Java API.  If you want to use that Java wrapper, you'll have to start maintaining it yourself or user another users' fork.

Comment: Can we use soundcloud to host our audio track and play it through an android app?

Answer (score 18):

[Go to Soundcloud developer site](https://developers.soundcloud.com/)

Click on My Apps.. Sign in Register your new app
Once you register you will have client id and client secret. Note it

**https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"TRACK ID"/stream?client_id="YOUR CLIENT ID"**

This API url will give you the sound file you want to play. You can use this url and parse the track id to play according to your need.

You can play around the url with different stuffs like getting user details,playlists.

[Refer this link for more API reference](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference)

Answer (score 5):

I update a library for new versions of android:
https://github.com/chemalarrea/soundcloudapi-android

Comment: Would be nice having some examples though

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late, but in case if somebody else is stuck.

You can check out [this repository](https://github.com/vpaliyX/SoundCloud-API). It's a simple wrapper of the SoundCloud API built with Retrofit2 and RxJava.