# What code do you need to type in order to add the soundcloud library to an app?

Tags: java, android, xml, soundcloud

I want to be able to search the entire SoundCloud library and add music to the app, so it can play. I chose SoundCloud because it is open source. How can I add this to my app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SoundCloud API in Java (Android App)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112014/how-to-use-soundcloud-api-in-java-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be best if you checked out their SDK/API:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/.

Not sure how to implement, haven't used it before, but that should be a good place to start.